# MySQL C++ Connector Error: mysqlcppconn-9-vs14.dll can´t be found

Tags: c++, mysql, debugging, header-files, mysql-connector

I have really no idear how to fix this problem. Everytime I try to debugg my Project, which create correctly, I have this system failure that mysqlcppconn-9-vs14.dll can´t be found.
Can someone help me please ?

Comment: First you have to find that file yourself. If it does exist tell your OS where to look. This document describes how the OS searches for dlls: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: Two easy ways to do that is either putting the required dll in the same folder as your executable or adding and entry to your windows PATH environment variable to contain the folder that this dll is located.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed mysql C++ Connector, this dll is located under bin folder.
Just copy it to your exe folder or add to PATH environment.